# Shafarevich conjecture for Abelian varieties over global function fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, characteristic-p

Let $S$ be a finite set of places of a global function field $K$. Are there finitely many Abelian varieties over $K$ with good reduction outside $S$? What if we exclude isotrivial families?

Comment: Presumably you want to fix the dimension $g$ of $A$, otherwise
once you have a single such $A$ you have infinitely many, 
namely its powers $A^n$.  Even then, I think this conjecture 
can fail already for $|S|=1$ due to Jacobians of
Artin-Schreier curves $y^p - y = P(x)$.  For $p=2$ and $p=3$
this already happens for $d=1$ ($y^2-y = x^3 + c t x$, $x^3-x = y^2 + c t y$).
Those examples must be isotrivial (constant $j$ invariant) but
I think that in characteristic $2$ the genus-3 curves $y^2-y = x^7 + ct$ 
give a nonisotrivial family with good reduction away from $t = \infty$.